# Countdown Clock (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, countdowntimer

I can get the following to work in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ausmxmp/3/), but not on my website. The digits don't display, which leads me to think there's something wrong with my js. Do I need to add window.onload somewhere and if so, where?

html:

```
<h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #00ECB9;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1 {
  color: #396;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}

#clockdiv {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv > div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #00BF96;
  display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #00816A;
  display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext {
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

JS:

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

// change date below to change countdown
var deadline = 'February 26 2016 17:00:00 GMT+12:00';
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle automatically puts your JavaScript in the `onload` function. If you don't have it that way on your website, simply wrap this portion of your JavaScript in the event listener:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // change date below to change countdown
    var deadline = 'February 26 2016 17:00:00 GMT+12:00';
    initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
});
```

A good explanation of the `window.onload` can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload):

> The `load` event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, **all of the objects in the document are in the DOM**, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the `onLoad` property when you click on the "JavaScript" button on JSFiddle, it specifies that the code included there is loaded after the rest of the content.

So try to add `window.onload =` right before you call your functions, as more precisely specified here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: That's great advice. Thank you.